# Has the Google API URL changed? https://apis.google.com/ is sending a 404 error

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

https://apis.google.com/ is giving an error 404.
All SSO connections to 3rd party apps from Google Mail give a 404 error too.

Comment: Welcome to stack its hard to understand what you mean by that question could you elaborate a little.  please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The URL for returning the Google APIs JS additnow is returning both a 404 and X-Frame-Options errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but from what I can see in the documentation for [APPS marketplace API](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/?hl=en) the URL is

```
URIs relative to https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2
```